# different import statement in objective c

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I was trying to debug a problem we were having in our React-Native on SDK

In our existing code, I see they have done

```
#import "CleverTap.h"
#import "CleverTapReactManager.h"
```

and [docs says to do](https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-react-native/blob/master/docs/integration.md)

```
#import <CleverTapSDK/CleverTap.h>
#import <CleverTapReact/CleverTapReactManager.h>
```

What is the difference between both the imports in swift? or they are the same?

Answer (score 1):

`#import ""` first check the header in project folder then goes to system library, and the `#import<>` checks for system headers.

Read: https://swift007blog.wordpress.com/2017/01/13/include-vs-import/